# How to add GestureListener handler to a control in cs code in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, event-handling, windows-phone-7

I don’t understand how to use some features from Windows Phone Toolkit in cs code in Silverlight (more precise, I don’t understand how to use GestureListener). I saw many examples of using GestureListener in xaml like this

```
<Image Source="something.jpg">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="image_Tap" Hold="image_Hold" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

And this works fine, but I create images dynamically and want dynamically add gesture handlers in cs code. Can someone give an example how to do the same thing only in cs code?

Answer (score 12):

SetGestureListener was deprecated , that`s right, instead you can use GetGestureListener like this

```
var gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(img);
gl.DoubleTap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(GestureListenerDoubleTap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Attached properties typically have a *SetPropertyName* and *GetPropertyName* method pair that correspond to the above XAML. I don't have experience with the Windows Phone 7 specifically, but the above would probably be done as:

```
GestureService.SetGestureListener(myImage, new GestureListener {
    Tap = "image_Tap",
    Hold = "image_Hold"
});
```

If those `Tap` and `Hold` properties are images, you will need to load some BitmapImage objects programmatically instead of strings.

Comment: SetGestureListener should not be called from code. It is used when the listener is declared in XAML. GetGestureListener is the correct way, it will create a new one if it doesn't already exist.